# Windows Registry DWORD Returns -1 on GetValue

Tags: vb.net, types, windows-10, registry

Firstly, apologies if this is a duplicate - I can't believe I'm the first to need to ask this question but I just can't find an existing answer (here or on Google).

I'm trying to read the value of a registry entry using the following VB.Net code (forgive any shonky formatting and the magic number; this is just quick and dirty test code):

```
Module modMain

    Private Const REG_KEY As String = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters"
    Private Const REG_VALUE As String = "FileSizeLimitInBytes"

    Sub Main()

        Dim strReturn As String = ""
        Dim lngNumBytes As Long = 0

        strReturn = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(REG_KEY, REG_VALUE, "-99")
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes: " & strReturn.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("Current registry value: " & (CDbl(strReturn) / 1048576).ToString() & " (MB)")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

The output is as follows:

> Bytes: -1
>
> Current registry value: -9.5367431640625E-07 (MB)

I have tried getting the DWORD value for other entries in that key and they all return correctly. The only difference is that the value in this case is very large: 4,294,967,295 (the other DWORD values are between 0 and 1,000,000). I have tried using various data types to accept the returned value (Int64, Int32, Double, Long and Object) but they all either fail completely or return -1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: One suspicion, I don't know but your total given code works for me. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1m8e.png), but that outputs `Bytes: 50000000` and `Current registry value: 47.6837158203125 (MB)` for me. Maybe it's related problem to your system architecture.

Comment: @LinuXMan - that's the standard value for that registry entry and would work on my machine too; it's the larger value of  4,294,967,295 that returns -1 every time. (The value in question is the maximum file size the web client will allow to be up/downloaded and  4,294,967,295 is the maximum value allowed.)

Comment: The corresponding DWORD value, in .Net, is initialized as Int32, not UInt32 (you can find this topic marked as an issue that won't be fixed). So you need to write it and read it as a QWORD.

Comment: Here, I've found it [Registry.GetValue returns an Int32 for REG_DWORD instead of an Uint32](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24954)

Comment: @Jimi - that's an answer, I'd say; I tried creating a new QWORD with the same name (renamed the old one DWORD first) and it works perfectly. So long as the web client service accepts a QWORD (more testing to follow) then I have a solution; if not, well, yours is still the right answer. Write it up and I will very gratefully accept it. Thanks.